# Anonymous block-level boxes and float

Tags: html, css

The output of `div#float` is unexpected:

```css
#absolute{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
}
#float{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Title</p>
Hello World!
<div id="absolute"></div>
<div id="float"></div>
</div>
```

According to [W3C anonymous-block-level](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level) , there should be a Anonymous block-level box around the inline-element `Hello World!`. (`<div id="anonymous-block-box">Hello World!</div>`). I expect the output should be:

```css
#absolute{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
}
#float{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Title</p>
<div id="anonymous-block-box">Hello World!</div>
<div id="absolute"></div>
<div id="float"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: some answers (aka newbies ) dont seem to understand my question. If you dont know what `anonymous-block-level ` is, you might not understand this question well.

Comment: A block-level element with a display property value other than table will generate a principal box block. A principal box will contain either block boxes or inline boxes as children, never both. If the element contains a mix of block-level and inline children, **anonymous block boxes** will be generated where necessary, so that the principal box will only contain block boxes.

Comment: I know what you refer to. I think that the flow of the elements change if you have a float element inside of the container overriding the `block` state to the `inline` element (by the anonymous block) and treat the `inline` element as it is. It has sense because it place the inline element as it would with `float` elements (as put in the specs).

Comment: Anonymous boxes don't affect layout in certain ways that non-anonymous boxes do, however the CSS2.1 spec is not clear on this, and it is expected to be clarified in css-box-3.

Answer (score 0):

The specs that you link above are only talking about `blocks`. If you are talking about `floats` then you should refer to this [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats).

Here you can see (highlited by me):

> if **inline-level** boxes are placed on the line **before a left float** is encountered that fits in the remaining line box space, **the left float is placed on that line**, aligned with the top of the line box, and then **the inline-level boxes already on the line are moved accordingly to the right of the float**

That explains why your `inline` element is displayed on the right side of the `float` element.

Answer (score 0):

The `inline element` get itself into the empty space if this space will contain it so when you made `float:left` to `div#float` it is leaving some space in its right so the `inline-element` go to this space.

if you want the `#float` to be under inine-element you should remove float:left from it so it will be display:block and in this case the inline-element will not find empty space beside it so it will be as your expectation

```css
#absolute{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
}
#float{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
  //float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Title</p>
Hello World!
<div id="absolute"></div>
<div id="float"></div>
</div>
```